# "Invalid Object name" error thrown by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLinkAssetToModule]
(   -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
@Module_ID int,
@Asset_ID int
)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Insert Into [dbo].[Modules_Assets_Link] (Modules_ID, Assets_ID, DateCreated) 
VALUES (@Module_ID, @Asset_ID, GETDATE());

END
```

When I clicked "save", it gave me "Invalid object name 'dbo.spLinkAssetToModule'" error. Does anyone know the reason? Is it related to access rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stored procedure by using `CREATE PROCEDURE`, not `ALTER PROCEDURE`.